# Can thread be used analogously with queue, or do they mean separate things?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I was reading through [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/79150/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-2) great tutorial when I came accross the following line (as background: we were learning how to use `dispatch_apply` to replace a `for` loop and concurrently download photos):

> Be aware that although you have code that will add the photos in a thread safe manner, the ordering of the images could be different depending on which thread finishes first.

This line really threw me off for some reason. I thought `dispatch_apply` will run a task on one **concurrent thread**, `GlobalUserInitiatedQueue`, not multiple different threads. He calls the method by saying:

```
 dispatch_apply(addresses.count, GlobalUserInitiatedQueue) {
```

So is `GlobalUserInitiatedQueue` one thread, multiple threads, and what's the difference between a thread and a queue? From what it seems, they're used analogously. Does that mean a concurrent queue has multiple threads running at the same time?

Thanks -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the guide:

> "Concurrent queues (also known as a type of global dispatch queue)
>   execute one or more tasks concurrently, but tasks are still started in
>   the order in which they were added to the queue. The currently
>   executing tasks run on distinct threads that are managed by the
>   dispatch queue. The exact number of tasks executing at any given point
>   is variable and depends on system conditions."

It can't be clearer than that. Multiple threads, start in the order of the tasks on the queue but finishing in no specific order.

I love tutorials and material that is aim to explains stuff in great details. However, when in doubts, I always go back to the Apple official documentations.

Comment: Wow, this is perfect! Thanks! So multiple threads are run on the same queue! Another line says, "All dispatch queues are themselves thread-safe in that you can access them from multiple threads simultaneously." what exactly does he mean by this?

Comment: The structure of the queue is locked when it gets modified and read. Basically, there is a mutex on the enqueue and dequeue operations.

Comment: Aha! Thanks again John! And now looking at the documentation, like you said, it's right there! :D "Dispatch queues themselves are thread safe. In other words, you can submit tasks to a dispatch queue from any thread on the system without first taking a lock or synchronizing access to the queue."

Comment: Thanks John! I have one more question and then I'm wrapping it up for the night: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816131/why-is-asynchronous-network-testing-difficult-in-objective-c-swift